# Filtering by ObjectId type with HotChocolate

Tags: c#, graphql, hotchocolate

I am trying to create a Graphql Schema and schema is crating but I cannot see a filtering option for Id (which is MongoDb ObjectId type). Could you tell me what I am missing? I would like to filter by Id as well but there is no like that option on created schema. You can see my test implementation below for that.

```
public class Startup
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            TypeConversion.Default.Register<string, ObjectId>(from => ObjectId.Parse(from));
            TypeConversion.Default.Register<ObjectId, string>(from => from.ToString());            
            services.AddSingleton<IAuthorService, InMemoryAuthorService>();

            services.AddGraphQL(s => SchemaBuilder.New()
                .AddServices(s)
                .AddType<AuthorType>()
                .AddQueryType<Query>()
                .BindClrType<ObjectId, IdType>()
                .Create());
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UsePlayground(new PlaygroundOptions
                {
                    QueryPath = "/api",
                    Path = "/playground"
                });
            }
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseGraphQL("/api");
        }
    }
 public class AuthorType : ObjectType<Author>
    {
        protected override void Configure(IObjectTypeDescriptor<Author> descriptor)
        {
            descriptor.Field(t => t.Id)
                     .Type<IdType>()
                     .Resolver(c => c.Parent<Author>().Id);
            descriptor.Field(a => a.AuthorId).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.Name).Type<StringType>();
            descriptor.Field(a => a.Surname).Ignore();
        }
    }
    public class Author
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }

    public class Query
    {
        private readonly IAuthorService _authorService;            

        public Query(IAuthorService authorService)
        {
            _authorService = authorService;               
        }
        [UsePaging]
        [UseFiltering]
        public IQueryable<Author> Authors() => _authorService.GetAll();    
      
    }


    public interface IAuthorService
    {
        IQueryable<Author> GetAll();
    }

    public class InMemoryAuthorService : IAuthorService
    {
        private IList<Author> _authors;

        public InMemoryAuthorService()
        {
            _authors = new List<Author>()
            {
                new Author() {Id = ObjectId.Parse("5e4442c28ae77cb23386b911"), AuthorId = 1, Name = "Name 1", Surname = "Surname 1"},
                new Author() {Id = ObjectId.Parse("5e4442c28ae77cb23386b912"), AuthorId = 2, Name = "Name 2", Surname = "Surname 2"},
                new Author() {Id = ObjectId.Parse("5e4442c28ae77cb23386b913"),AuthorId = 3, Name = "Name 4", Surname = "Surname 3"}
            };
        }

        public IQueryable<Author> GetAll()
        {
            return _authors.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 4):

This should work when you bind the ObjectId type and register a serialised

```cs
builder.BindRuntimeType<ObjectId, IdType>();
builder.AddTypeConverter<ObjectId, string>(o => o.ToString());
builder.AddTypeConverter<string,ObjectId>(o => ObjectId.Parse(o));
```

You can read more about scalars in the docs here:
https://chillicream.com/docs/hotchocolate/defining-a-schema/scalars/#custom-converter